# Updating local variables in VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to increase the ordinal number of the guess for the current game cycle by 1. I have set the value initially at 0 but it doesn't update after 1. Same goes for number of tries. I have set the value at 21, and it soon updates to 20 but not after that.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
    Private value As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.value = rand.Next(minValue:=1, maxValue:=30)  'Setting up random number

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim guess As Integer        'guess number
        Dim numTry As Integer       'No. of trys
        Dim OrdNo As Integer        'Ordinal Number
        Dim Score As Integer        'Score

        Score = 0                   'Initial value of score set as 0
        numTry = 21
        OrdNo = CInt(1)             'Initial value of ordinal set as 1 
        guess = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        OrdNo = +1
        Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)

        'Show Message Box if the guess is not within the range
        If 1 > guess Then
            MessageBox.Show("Input within the range (1-30)", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Show Message Box if the guess is not within the range
        If guess > 30 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Input within the range (1-30)", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is larger than the lucky number
        If guess > Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "The Lucky Number is smaller than your guess"
            OrdNo = OrdNo + 1
            Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            Label4.Text = CStr(numTry)
        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is smaller than lucky number
        If guess < Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "The Lucky Number is larger than your guess"
            OrdNo = OrdNo + 1
            Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            Label4.Text = CStr(numTry)

        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is equal to the lucky number
        If guess = Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "Congratulations ! This is the lucky number"
            Score = +10 'Increase the score by 10
            Label6.Text = CStr(Score)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            OrdNo = 1
            Me.value = rand.Next(minValue:=1, maxValue:=30)

            If numTry = 0 Then Application.Exit()

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: variables declared in a function or sub are local to the function or sub, and are destroyed when it is over. move those variable declarations up outside of the function to make it module level, and the variable will live for the lifetime of the class.

Comment: Do u mean should i make it a global variable ? If i do that i am not able to set the initial value of that variable ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what's happening every time the button is clicked.  To simplify, let's just look at one variable:

```
Dim numTry As Integer
numTry = 21
numTry = numTry - 1
```

So every time the button is clicked, three things happen:

- Declare the variable
- Set it to 21
- Subtract 1

Every time.

But the only thing you *want* to happen every time is:

- Subtract 1

In that case, your variables shouldn't be re-declared and re-initialized with every button click.  Instead, move them to the class level.  Something like this:

```
Private numTry As Integer = 21

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' other code...
    numTry = numTry - 1
    ' other code...
End Sub
```

That way the variable itself is declared and initialized only once at the start of the object's lifespan, and then is updated with each button click.

(**Note:** This will behave differently in an *ASP.NET* situation, because the lifespan of the object is per-request.  In that case, rather than storing in a class-level variable, you'd want to store in some other persistence medium such as Session State.)